# MySQL GROUP BY function skips oddly some days

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a MySQL table with a bunch of appointments for a bunch of users. But I have detected a particular user whose appointments for `2018-09-26` and `2018-09-29` get skipped altogether, and I don't know why.

This is the code:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    appointments
WHERE
    appday >= '2018-09-26 00:00:00'
    AND 
    (
        user1 = 'User name'
        OR
        user2 = 'User name'
        OR
        user3 = 'User name'
    )
GROUP BY 
    DAY(appday)
ORDER BY
    appday ASC
```

`appday` is a `datetime` field. The funny thing is that it works for every other day and every other user, except for those mentioned. And this problem happens only with one particular user.

If I remove the Group By clause, the appointments for the mentioned days show up, it is until I add the Group By that they are not returned at all.

EDIT: this is the result it generates:
[image: groupby example]

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is generally invalid, at least from a logical point of view.  Please include some sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Also, what prompted you to use `GROUP BY` in the first place?  You are not computing any aggregates in your query.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Your query won't run on MySQL 8.0 with a default configuration because it violates `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (and as Tim mentioned, your query is currently nonsensical because `SELECT *` in a `GROUP BY` query doesn't mean anything).

Comment: I can see how the `SELECT *` could mean nothing. I use this query so I can make a list of all the days that do have an appointment, while I wont show anything about the days that are empty. So the user can see a list of only the days that have an event, and then I have another query to retrieve which events are those.

Comment: MySQL production version is 5.5. Development is 10, it doesn't work on either.

Comment: How can I share some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. I tried to approach the need on a different manner and so I did. Instead of querying inside the Group By, I chose to just do one query, and during the iteration check if the current DAY was the same as the previous, if so, no header was added.

Comment: Yes. Handle issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2):

For finding list of appointments  you don't need group by , `group by` normally applicable for aggregate function or if you want any groups distinctly , i just remove group by from your query

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        appointments
    WHERE
        appday >= '2018-09-26 00:00:00'
        AND 
        (
            user1 = 'User name'
            OR
            user2 = 'User name'
            OR
            user3 = 'User name'
        )

    ORDER BY
        appday
```

Comment: Thank you! The thing is, that I need to add a little header for each day that has events, that's why I group, so I can later iterate through each of those days. I added a picture to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have full information about your data set and all results but I feel you maybe needed the function dayofyear since you are extracting days over two months and not day which is a synonym for dayofmonth. The implication of using day is that you can only have unique numbers ranging from 1-31 which are all the potential dayofmonths.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day